# What is the current across the resistor given in the figure?

Tags: dc, power-electronics, network

The circuit is short circuit across the the resistor. What will be the current flow across the 30 ohm resistor?

[image]

Comment: Current flows **through**.  Voltage is measured across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume the 3A current flows across the short, then the voltage across the 30Ohm resistor is 0V and since the current source is ideal, it can have any voltage across it (even 0V), hence the solution is valid. On the other hand, if you assume the 3A current flows through the 30Ohm resistor then you have (3x30= 90V) developed across the current source. But then again, you have 90V developed across an ideal short (which violates KVL) and hence the only valid solution is the entire 3A current flows through the short.

Comment: Okay i understood that.
But, current flows through an element only when there  is a voltage drop across any element....since in this question - there is no voltage drop across the source. Then how is it possible that 3 A current is flowing?

Answer (score 0):

Given ideal components, no current will flow through the resistor, as there will be no voltage across it. 3 amps will flow through the current source and wire loop with no voltage drop, and there will be 0 volts across the current source, or the resistor.

In the real world, replace all the wires with very low value resistors and then do the arithmetic. The result depends on your wire resistance and length. If you use #14 solid copper, you'll have 2.525 milliohms per foot.